# Use an Inheritable Form Amongst Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have created a windows glass form that inherits from system.windows.forms.form and then I have placed it in a class library project.

I would now like to use this form in multiple other windows forms projects.  How do I do this?

I have created a reference to the class library but I don't know how to actually get the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want forms in your project to derive from your Glass Form from what I can tell.

Make sure that your GlassForm class is public; eg.

```
public class GlassForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
}
```

Now that you have verified it is public, for any form you wish to inherit from GlassForm, change the inherited class from Form to GlassForm. eg.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
}
```

To

```
public class MyForm : YourClassLibraryNamespace.GlassForm
{
}
```

Your form will now derive from GlassForm and will act as such in the WinForm designer as well. If you just meant that you want to use the form in your project in a calling sense, you can do what Bob Horn stated.

```
using YourClassLibraryNamespace;

public class MyForm : Form
{
    public void ShowGlassFormModal() {
        using (GlassForm form = new GlassForm()) {
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public void ShowGlassForm() {
        new GlassForm().Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, I got my self all confused with usercontrols.  Silly me.   One question: I presume if I add controls like textboxes to the glass form in the designer, then they will not show on the inherited form?

Comment: Anything you add to the parent class that others derive from will affect anything deriving from it. So if you do add a TextBox to GlassForm, and MyForm derives from GlassForm, it will also have that same textbox.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the case for me when using the class library. I am adding a textbox to the Glassform but it is not showing on my MyForm. MyForm is definately inheriting though because it has the glass appereance, so the code is working.  Also if I recreate the glass form in my winforms project the inheritance works correctly.  It seems to be related to inheriting from a form in a class library.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have your reference, all you need to do is use it. Add the form's namespace to your class file:

```
using NamespaceOfWindowsGlassForm;
```

Then use the form:

```
WindowsGlassForm form = new WindowsGlassForm();
```